# gridster auto height and width according to content

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, gridster

I am adding grids using the 'add_widget' method of Gridster. The widget is successfully added, but the unordered list (ul) width is smaller then its contents.

Can anybody tell me how I can resize the height and width in Gridster according to the content.

Comment: Can you not use the 'resize_widget' method? You might be able to use that along with supplying the width/height based on the containing elements dimensions. i.e. $(element).parent().width() or .height() and resize the widget to those?

Comment: OP, any news regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I did a couple years back was to recreate the style via javascript and then replace the old  with the new one. You'll also want to set {autogenerate_stylesheet_opt: false}. Hope this helps!

Reference: http://gridster.net/#autogenerate_stylesheet_opt

Comment: Your link is broken

Comment: Yea, I don't think library exists anymore. I'd use David Desandro's packery library instead. https://packery.metafizzy.co